# Update a member that falls between start and end date across a table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a member that falls between start and end date across a table using a stored procedure in SQL Server and it's not updating correctly. The same client may have multiple start and end dates. What I am doing wrong? Thank you

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMembership]
    
AS
DECLARE @RecordCount    int
DECLARE @ClientID       int
DECLARE @i              int 
    
UPDATE Client Set ActiveMember = 0
    
SELECT @RecordCount= Count(ClientID)
FROM dbo.Membership
INNER JOIN dbo.Account ON dbo.Membership.Receipt = dbo.Account.Receipt
WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
    
    SET @i = 1
    
    WHILE @i <= @RecordCount
    BEGIN
        SET ROWCOUNT @i
    
        SELECT @ClientID = ClientID
        FROM dbo.Membership
        INNER JOIN dbo.Account ON dbo.Membership.Receipt = dbo.Account.Receipt
        WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
    
        UPDATE Client Set ActiveMember = 1 WHERE ClientID = @ClientID;
    
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

Comment: Your code has some major issues going on. The first and most glaring is using a loop for this. The second is that in your loop you are getting the same ClientID over and over and over.

Comment: Be careful. Using BETWEEN with dates can be problematic. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: The same client may have multiple start and end dates.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever find yourself writing a loop for this kind of thing, you're almost certainly doing something very wrong. The entire procedure reduces to this:

```
UPDATE c
SET ActiveMember = CASE WHEN m.ClientID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN ( dbo.Membership m
    INNER JOIN dbo.Account a ON m.Receipt = a.Receipt
        AND current_timestamp BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
)  ON c.ClientID = m.ClientID
```

*I'm inferring the requirements for Client.ActiveMember are a current membership record (based on startdate/enddate) with a valid receipt (payment?).*

Comment: The same client may have multiple start and end dates.

Comment: @Jose Updated to account for that. Assuming any current membership is enough to make the client active, this will produce correct results. It could still join to more than one membership, but only if all of the matching records are current and paid.

Comment: `EXISTS` is probably more efficient and more correct than a join